# Routing and constructors in Angular Dart

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Not sure if this is a bug or not. When using a `RouteProvider`, the code within a controller constructor runs every time the route changes. So, in the following example, I call `fetchData()` to load the initial data that is loaded in a view.

```dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[my-controller]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MyController implements NgDetachAware {
  ...

  MyController(RouteProvider router) {
    linkId = router.parameters['linkId'];
    route = router.route.newHandle();
    fetchData();
  }
}
```

But anytime I navigate to a route, the code in the constructor executes, and the data gets fetched.

Is this a bug? If not, what is the correct way to set values when the view loads?

Comment: Yup, this is expected. Your controllers get destructed and constructed every time the route (and implicitly the associated controller) changes. Store your data in a service. Those are persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller is used inside the view then that view is destroyed and re-created every time route is re-entered or parameters change, so new instance of the controller is created.